# Testing BigNumber values in Hardhat unit tests the safest way?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, waffle

I have seen at least three different ways to test two BigNumbers.

- Using waffle BigNumber
- Convert toString()
- Cast to Number

As an example hardhat test with chai and waffle.

```js
const sendValueBN = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1337")
const storedValueBN = await ethers.provider.getBalance(contract.address)
...
// using waffle
expect(sendValueBN).to.equal(storedValueBN)

// toString()
assert.equal(sendValueBN.toString(), storedValueBN.toString())

// Cast to Number
assert.equal(Number(sendValueBN), Number(storedValueBN))
```

Can someone help me understand which one is preferred and why?

I ordered them in what I believe is the preferred order (top to bottom).
*Casting to Number is worst because i believe it has the risk of precision loss due to BigNumber 10<sup>18</sup> and a JavaScript Number is a double. But I am not sure even after reading [this](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/bignumber/).*

Answer (score 0):

the recommended way to compare `BigNumber` objects is to use the `toString()` method, because we compare the actual values of the `BigNumber` objects as strings.